# login to wso2 IS using salesforce users

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have requirement where my sales-force users can be authenticated to my web application via wso2 identity server.

I goggled and found one blog [salesforce-wso2](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/04/30/integrating-salesforce-with-wso2-identity-server-as-saml2-sso-idp/)
I have similar requirement to above blog.

When i followed this blog it did not worked. I am sure there are missing steps not mentioned there.

For integration of Salesforce and WSO2 i also followed [configure salesforce](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Outbound+Provisioning+with+Salesforce)

But this also did not worked. When i create users on WSO2 i cannot see on my salesforce domain.
Also there are no steps mentioned how to enable salesforce as an IDP which is per-requisite of the integration i guess.

Can anyone let me know proper document or what is missing from above links?

Comment: Could you please let us know issue that you have experienced when integrating with Salesforce as federated authentication ?

Comment: I have configured travelocity sameple webapp to be logged in with salesforce account.

Comment: I have configured travelocity sample webapp to be logged in with salesforce account.

 I followed this link to register webapp  : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0

Then i configured travelocity.com app to use salesforce users to login.
But when i click proceed to login with my salesforce account , after login it does not redirect m back to travelocity.com home page

Comment: Also documents mentioned on website lack example. Its difficult to understand what is happening..

Comment: I also found my /commonauth URL is not accisible. This URL is giving error page and message like :
"Something went wrong during the authentication process. Please try signing in again."

Comment: Now i am able to login to sample travelocity login with wso2 users i.e. normal authentication, but when i click on salesforce login and enter my credentials i am able to login but it redirects me to my account home page. Ideally it should redirect me to travelocity web application.

Comment: It is not possible to give some idea with out error logs... you can go through by yourself and find out what cause for the issue..  as there is SAML, tracing SAML request/response may be helpful for you.  http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/09/17/troubleshooting-saml2-web-sso-scenarios/